# Product images not changing on swatches click on product listing pages

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches

I am trying to change configurable product images on clicking swatches for product listing pages. But it is not working. It is working fine for product details page.
Product detail page
[image]

It is working fine here. But it is not working for category pages or product listing page.
[image]

I tried to look for an answer and found out that I need to update my attribute values that I am using for configurable product. I have updated all the values but it made it work only for product page and not for  category or product listing pages.

The attribute values in admin
[image]

[image]

Plz guide me how I can make it work for product listing pages too.

Comment: Your settings are correct. Did you try with run cache and indexing command?

Comment: yes tried after your suggestion, but did not worked

Comment: Check is there any error in the console?

Comment: I have moved my changes to live, and it is working fine on live. I am getting this issue on staging setup. Maybe staging has files missing or something else. Thanks for your guidance